# Creating Automated InstallShield Setups

Tags: installation, installshield

I have created a small DLL to Automate my applications setup process.
This works fine with one application but fails from a second application.

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
        ' Create Object 
        oInstallShieldProject = New ISWiProject
```

The exception message is:

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {....} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0035 Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0035 (CTL_E_FILENOTFOUND)

Any ideas why one application works fine and the other does not. Both applications are running on the same 64bit Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Are they both running as 32-bit programs? If not, they need to be.

Comment: They are both being compiled as Any CPU and both have Target CPU is AnyCPU.